# Unable to pass the value from .module file to JS using the implementation given below

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

.module file

```
function taxonomy_fancybox_menu(){
     $items['fetch-popup-markup-data/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Store markup',
  'page callback' => 'ajax_fetch_markup_popup_data',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
}

function ajax_store_markup_popup_data($fieldname){

  $field = $_POST['field'];

  // $html = $_POST['html'];
     $output = theme('taxonomy_fancybox_term_field_display_template',array(
     'rows' => $_SESSION['taxonomy_fancybox'][$field]['rows'],
     'field'=>$field
    )
   );
     drupal_set_message($field);
   drupal_set_message($output);
   watchdog('taxonomy_fancybox','<pre> OUTPUT:'. $output . '</pre>');
   drupal_json_output(array('output'=>$output));
  // $_SESSION['taxonomy_fancybox'][$field]['html'] = $html;
  // drupal_json_output($html);
}
```

JS Implementation:

```
$('.popup-data').each(function(){
           var field = $(this).attr('field');
           var html  = $(this).html();
           $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json', 
             data: {field: field},
             url: '/fetch-popup-markup-data/'+field+'/',
             success: function(ht) {
              alert(ht);
              alert('got the html if not check in the console');
              console.log(ht);
              if (ht !=''){
                $('#'+field+'-popup-data').html(ht);
              }
             }
            // Change site name to current user name.
           });
        });
```

Whatever data I am passing in `drupal_json_output()` does not pass to JS and when I try to check the value in `watchdog`, I see the data, also see it in `drupal_set_message()` but when I check the html on the success function of the POST by sending `alert()` it returns empty value,even the `console.log()` returns empty value, what can be the reason for the empty value ?

Comment: Look into Drupal JavaScript behaviors and passing js settings to your JavaScript functions. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api .

Answer (score 1):

Router:

```
$.ajax{{
...
 url: '/fetch-popup-markup-data/'+field+'/'
```

vs router

```
$items['store-popup-markup-data/%'] = array(..
```

not dissimilarity. change dataType `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'html'`

You can try code below:

```
$('.popup-data').each(function(){
  var field = $(this).attr('field');
  var html  = $(this).html();
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json', 
     data: {field: field},
     url: '/store-popup-markup-data/'+field+'/',
     success: function(ht) {
       alert(ht);
       alert('got the html if not check in the console');
       console.log(ht);
       var jsonHt = $.parseJSON(ht);
       if (jsonHt.output !=''){
         $('#'+field+'-popup-data').html(jsonHt.output);
       }
     }

   });
 });
```

Comment: Hi , sorry I have updated my answer and code the menu was incorrect ,  I have corrected it, will update you whether the rest of suggestion helps